# Transfer data from Mat/oclMat to cl_mem (OpenCV + OpenCL)

Tags: opencv, opencl

I am working on a project that needs a lot of OpenCL code. I am using OpenCV's ocl module to develop my project faster but there are some functions not implemented and I will have to write my own OpenCL code.

My question is this: what is the quickest and cheapest way to transfer data from Mat and/or oclMat to a cl_mem array.  Re-wording this, is there a good way to transfer or enqueue (clEnqueueWriteBuffer) data from oclMat or Mat?

Currently, I am using a for-loop to read data from Mat (or download from oclMat and then use for-loops) and then enqueuing it. This is turning out to be costly, hence my question.

Thanks to anyone who sees this question :)

Comment: Hi, here is something that worked for me. Assume that x is an oclMat initialized with "1". 

oclMat x(100, 100, CV_32FC1, Scalar(1));
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&x.data);


This worked for me and I got this idea by digging through the ocl code given in OpenCV. Please let me know if you think something might go wrong here. Thanks!!

Comment: Thats the proper way to use it. You are not even using another buffer, but directly the original oclMat buffer. Be careful NOT to use the original oclMat while you use its buffer for other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a set of interop functions for the [Boost.Compute](https://github.com/kylelutz/compute) library which ease the use of OpenCL and OpenCV. Take a look at the [`opencv_copy_mat_to_buffer()`](https://github.com/kylelutz/compute/blob/master/include/boost/compute/interop/opencv/core.hpp#L28) function.

There are also functions for copying from a OpenCL buffer back to the host `cv::Mat` and for copying `cv::Mat` to OpenCL `image2d` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate memory bandwidth, achieved in Host-Device interconnections.

If you get ~60% and more of maximal bandwidth, you've nothing to do, memory transfer is as fast as it can be. But if your bandwidth results are lower that 55% - 60% of theoretical maximum, try to use multiple command queues with unblocking operations (don't forget to sync at the end). Also, pay attention on avg image size. Small data transfers usually have big overhead rate.

If your Device uses shared memory, use memory mapping instead of read/write, this may dramatically save time. If Device has it's own memory, apply pinned memory technique, which is well described in NVIDIA OpenCL Best Practices Guide.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time! Something else worked for me -- please check my comment on the original question.

Comment: Using appropriate constructor means that copying goes under the hood. I assume, that CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR flag is used at memory object creation stage. Though, if you're happy with solution, that's good :)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of oclMat states that there is some sort of functionality to the underlying ocl buffer data:

```
//! pointer to the data(OCL memory object)
uchar *data;
```

If you have clMat already in the device, you can simply perform a copy buffer from `clMat.data` to your `clBuffer`. But you will have to hack a little bit the memory, accessing some private members of the oclMat

Something like:

```
clEnqueueCopyBuffer(command_queue, (clBuffer *)oclMat.data, dst_buffer, 0, 0, size);
```

NOTE: Take care with the casting, maybe you have to cast another pointer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time! Something else worked for me -- please check my comment on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

For your comment, it's right. The oclMat can be used as cl_mem(void *) for device,  since it was alloced by OpenCL device.

Additionally, you can creat svm memory(for example void* svmdata) at first, and then assign a Mat like: Mat A(rows, cols, CV_32FC1, svmdata).
Now you can process the Mat A between host and device without memory copy. 
(PS. The svm memory is the new character of OCL, it can be created by clSVMAlloc).