# OpenGL rendering to Framebuffer, transfer to OpenCV Umat for OpenCL accelerated processing

Tags: opencv, opengl, rendering, opencl, gpu

In an older version of OpenCV I could render using OpenGL to the backbuffer, used `glreadpixels` to "copy" the pixels to an OpenCV image (iplimage?) for some processing (blurring, templatematching with another OpenCV-loaded image).  However that would cost me with the transfer from GPU to CPU and then if I wanted to display it, back to the GPU.

Now I can do something similar with just OpenGL and OpenCL, by using `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects` and I do not have to transfer at all.  I OpenGL render to a Framebuffer and let OpenCL take control of it.

However this forces me to write my own OpenCL kernels (nobody has time for that...actually terribly hard to debug OpenCL on an Nvidia) for whatever processing I would like to do.  Now that OpenCV has some great OpenCL-accelerated processes I would like to try them out.

So my question: Is it possible to render to the Framebuffer (or another GL context on the GPU), give control (or copy) to an OpenCV context (umat?) for OpenCL-accelerated processing?  If so, how (big picture, key components)?

I have a feeling I can use `cv::ogl::Buffer` to wrap the buffer, but the documentation is not exactly clear on this, and then copy it using `ogl::Buffer::copyTo`. similar: [Is it possible to bind a OpenCV GpuMat as an OpenGL texture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086519/is-it-possible-to-bind-a-opencv-gpumat-as-an-opengl-texture)

other ref: [Transfer data from Mat/oclMat to cl_mem (OpenCV + OpenCL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356592/transfer-data-from-mat-oclmat-to-cl-mem-opencv-opencl)

Comment: This is a path I'm currently going down by using the  UMat handle (also something I can not find much documentation on): 
`cv::Umat x;

err = clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects(ocl_queue, 1, (cl_mem*)x.handle(ACCESS_WRITE), 0, NULL, NULL);`

which compiles, but doesn't work... maybe I have to define x when I create to match the size of the GLbuffer?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: I might have, it was a year+ ago. I did find: https://fossies.org/linux/opencv/samples/opengl/opengl_interop.cpp  if you are using the opengl portion of opencv.   I think I tried to create a MAT, then used clCreateImage2D using the "data" from the MAT file... i.e. image = clCreateImage2D(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, &format, mat.cols, mat.rows, 0, (void*)mat.data, &err);  I then rendered using GL and used the clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects to move it to CL and CV simultaneously... I know that is a terrible answer, I gave up soon after.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possibly - now. I wrote [demos](https://github.com/kallaballa/GCV) that demonstrate OpenGL/OpenCL/VAAPI interop. [tetra-demo](https://github.com/kallaballa/GCV/blob/main/src/tetra/tetra-demo.cpp) renders a rotating tetrahedron using OpenGL, passes the framebuffer (actually a texture attached to a framebuffer) on to OpenCV/CL (as a cv::UMat) and encodes it to VP9. All on the GPU. The only problem is, that the required fixes reside in my [OpenCV 4.x fork](https://github.com/kallaballa/opencv/tree/GCV) and you'll have to build it yourself.
It also requires two OpenCL extensions: cl_khr_gl_sharing and cl_intel_va_api_media_sharing

There are two open github issues addressing my efforts:

- [OpenGL/OpenCL and VAAPI/OpenCL interop at the same time](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22607)
- [Capture MJPEG from V4l2 using VAAPI hardware acceleration to OpenCL using VAAPI/OpenCL interop](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22622)

Answer (score 1):

The opencv-opengl interop is now very easy to use (Love goes to the devs)!
I can now use OpenCV as postprocessing efffects without copying to the CPU.

Initializing texture and opencv wrapper:

```cpp
cv::ogl::Texture2D texture;
GLuint fbo_texture;

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(1, &fbo_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture);
<...>
texture = cv::ogl::Texture2D(cv::Size(screen_width, screen_height), cv::ogl::Texture2D::Format::RGBA, fbo_texture, false);
```

Rendering to FBO, blurring and displaying (using fixed-function pipeline):

```cpp
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
//draw to FBO
<...>
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);


cv::UMat u;
cv::ogl::convertFromGLTexture2D(texture, u); // The magic
cv::blur(u, u, cv::Size(10,10));
cv::ogl::convertToGLTexture2D(u, texture); // The magic


texture.bind();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f);
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

And don't forget to initialize the opencl of opencv after creating the opengl context:

```cpp
if (cv::ocl::haveOpenCL())
{
   cv::ogl::ocl::initializeContextFromGL();
}
```